# How Do I Embed A Private Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set up a custom map for internal use within the company I work for but I'm having a little trouble doing so.

I don't want people to have to sign in with a Google account or anything and I want to embed this on to it's own page on our server.

I've set the map to private and of course, the map doesn't show up - is there any way that I can keep the map private but still embed it?

I'm guessing I'd need to do this with the Google Maps API but so far, I've struggled to find a tutorial or anything that provides the answer.

I'm using a simple iFrame so far like so:

```
<iframe src="MAP URL HERE" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'private map'?

Comment: The map is created with Google Maps Engine Lite - there is a 'Share' button with the options to make it public, let anyone with a link see it or make it private, so only the owner can see it.

Comment: In my knowledge, there's no such feature to make map a private map unless you applied page-level authentication for members you want to show the map to. If you're okay with that, I can help you setting up Google Maps. You can customize a lot of things using it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using OpenLayers with an OpenStreetMap tile layer. This is open sourced api and it allows you to create custom maps where you can allow people to add markers, lines, polygons etc to the map with information about those features. I have provided a getting started link below.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example

Considering you want the map to be private, then this depends on the website in general or the intranet settings so that only people on the server can view the map.